# Analyzing quantitative data in WEKA

Tags: weka

Hi My dataset contains only quantitative data(numerical). It doesn't have any class attributes. The dataset contains with sales of different years. I need to analyze the data in different ways. Can I use WEKA for this analysis? I tried to use WEKA tool. But it seemed I cannot proceed with WKA unless I have class variables for the dataset. Please kindly give me a hint.

Comment: It may helpful if you can define what type of analyzes do you want.

Comment: I have a set of sales data of a retailed shop. Nearly sales of 20 years. I need to analyze the sales of the future based on historical value. I don't think regression will be a better solution for this. I found this article, http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/DATAMINING/Time+Series+Analysis+and+Forecasting+with+Weka which gives a clue hw to do this. But seems it needs a new plugin. There are many such sales parallely selling by the shop. So need to compare the sales between the products as well to identify the most profitable area to sell products